# refit of flexmix in R

Tags: r

I am new to flexmix in R and would like to have some help. I apologize for the messing format, as this is my first post as well.

I have two DVs in a dataset, Y1 and Y2.

```
summary(dataset1.nomiss$Y1)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 

  3.000   3.000   3.000   4.202   4.000  28.000 

summary(dataset1.nomiss$Y2)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 

  1.000   2.000   3.000   3.838   6.000  11.000 

> dataset1.nomiss$Y1

  3  4  7  1  1  3  1  4  8  4  9  4  1  2  7  7  3  1  2  6  4  1  3  2  5  1  1  2  3  8  1  4  9  1  1  3  4  3  2  2 11  1  2  1  2  7  5  3  3  3  2  4  8  1  4  4
  1  4  5  3  1  2  8  3  3  4  1  1  9  4  2  6  1  2  2  1  7  3  6  8  1  3  6  3  1  1  1  1  7  9  8  2  1  4  2  3  2  4  1  2  4  4  9  2  2  5  3  2  5  2  6 10
  8  2  2  4  4  2  2  5  3  8  3  1  2  8  3  8  8  5  6  7  4  3 11  4  2  4  7  1  1  7  5  2  7  9  7 10  4  2  3  3  7  4  7  1  1  1  1  1  7  1  1  4  1  8  1  8
  2  9  4  3  3


> dataset1.nomiss$Y1  # Guessing this was supposed to be Y2

  4  3  6  3  6  3  3  3  3  3  5  4  3  4  4  3  6  3  3  6  8  3  3  3  5  3  3  3  4  3  3  5 28  3  3  3  4  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  5  6  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 28
 3  3  3  6  3  3  3  3  3  8  3  3  3  6  3  3  3  3  3  3 12  3  4  3  3  9 16  3  3  3  4  4  3  3  3  4  3  3  3  3  3  5  3  3  3  3  3  5  3  3  3  3  3  3  9  3
 4  3  7  3 18  4  3  8  3  3  3  3  3  7  3  7 11  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  6  6  3  3 11 14  3  3  3  3  3  4  3  4  3  3  3  5  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
 3  3  3  3  3
```

I am having trouble refitting Y1 as follows.

```
Call:

flexmix(formula = Y1 ~ Condition + AGE + RACE + CESD + SAQ_overall + SAQ_certainty + SAQ_importance, data = dataset1.nomiss, 
    k = 2)

       prior size post>0 ratio

Comp.1 0.266   46     46     1

Comp.2 0.734  127    127     1

'log Lik.' 3871.355 (df=21)
AIC: -7700.709   BIC: -7634.49 

> model_1.refit<-refit(model_1)

**Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit$hessian)) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[11,11] = 0**
```

However, Y2 worked fine

```
Call:
flexmix(formula = Y2 ~ Condition + AGE + RACE + CESD + SAQ_overall + SAQ_certainty + SAQ_importance, data = dataset1.nomiss, 
    k = 2)

       prior size post>0 ratio

Comp.1 0.661  111    172 0.645

Comp.2 0.339   62    108 0.574

'log Lik.' -358.9611 (df=21)
AIC: 759.9222   BIC: 826.1413 


> model_2.refit<-refit(model_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

When one model effort returns an error message saying that a "singular system" resulted, it means that one of the matrices that was constructed could not be processed because of linear dependence of the columns. It's not an error of coding, but rather a situation in the data that prevents the mathematical "machinery" from proceeding. You can investigate some of the possibilities by looking at the correlation of Y1 with the predictors each of the predictors singly:

```
with(dataset1.nomiss, sapply( list( Condition , AGE , RACE , CESD , SAQ_overall , 
                     SAQ_certainty, SAQ_importance),
                              cor, y=Y1)
```

If none of the those individual correlations a 1.0, then you should then look at three-way tables of Y1 with pairs of categorical variables. Without a better description of the nature of these variables it's difficult to be specific, but I would think that AGE was not likely to be a concern as long as it is not categorical. The SAQ variables cannot be commented on since you haven't laid out the data situation in any detail.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this.